# Jquery Jscrollpane - Internal links force pane to scroll

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane

I am using Jscrollpane v2.0.0beta10 last updated 2011-04-17 with Jquery library v1.5.2.

My scrollpane contains a list of images, which are wrapped in a links. Despite the type of a link used, when clicking on an image, it forces the pane to scroll to the end in FF 3.6.16 and in IE 8, the last links causes the pane to scroll to the beginning.

Please note that I have tried previous versions of the jquery library as well as previous versions of Jscrollpane script.

Does anyone perhaps have advice on how I can fix this issue?

A test version can be previewed at http://jsbin.com/amure6

Thx in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of problems with your example which make it hard to see what might be going on:

- The code to calculate the width of the image will only work if the image is cached (you would need to check on document load to get the width of non cached images)
- "ScrollGalleryCntnr" doesn't have an overflow of "auto". This means the page will be inaccessible without jScrollPane (and possibly with it).

I do see the problem in your example in Firefox even with a couple of changes made:

http://jsbin.com/amure6/4

However, a similar basic example doesn't show the problem (scroll down and click the "Google" link within the pane):

http://jsfiddle.net/VYcDZ/95/

I'm not sure what the difference is?